# xmlsec1 | Is it possible to input the xml template as a string instead of pointing to a filename?

Tags: xmlsec1

Normally I would do something like:

`$ xmlsec1 --sign --privkey-pem MY_CERT_FILE.pem MY_TEMPLATE_FILE.xml`

The above would spit out the signed xml string on the terminal screen.

I would like to do something like this though:

`$ xmlsec1 --sign --privkey-pem MY_CERT_FILE.pem '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Envelope><Data>Hello, World!</Data></Envelope>'`

Obviously the above command does NOT work.

I am hoping for some sort of option flag before the xml input string which would allow me to accomplish just that.

I also asked this same question at the repo issue queue. [Click here](https://github.com/lsh123/xmlsec/issues/273) to see it.

Comment: There are two dirty solutions for this, 
`$ xmlsec1 --sign --privkey-pem cert.pem <(echo 'XML TEMPLATE STRING HERE')` or `$ xmlsec1 --sign --privkey-pem cert.pem /dev/stdin <<<'XML TEMPLATE STRING HERE'`. See details at https://superuser.com/questions/939746/pass-text-to-program-expecting-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo maintainer says this is not possible at the moment but accepts pull requests. [Click here](https://github.com/lsh123/xmlsec/issues/273#issuecomment-529566033) to see his answer and [Click here](https://github.com/lsh123/xmlsec/issues/273#issuecomment-529246950) to see the current workaround solutions.

Unfortunately I do not possess the C programing skills necessary to pull off a patch.

If any of you knows C programing and wish to contribute, please take this one for the nation, thank you.